# How to Compare rows of a dataframe to an 2D Array List - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, arraylist

My goal is to compare a DataFrame row to every item in a 2D array list.

**Here is my list = mylist**

```
1       2000
2       2000a
3       2000b
```

**Here is my Dataframe = df**

```
RPN      Source       city  
1       netflix       baltimore
1       netflix       baltimore
2       hulu          orlando
4       hulu          houston
```

As explained above, I would like to create a new column from a list that compares each RPN in my DataFrame to the first position of mylist. If RPN is in mylist, take the second position of the array associated with it and append it to the a list to be joined to the data frame. If not found just use RPN.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
RPN      Source          city           npi
1       netflix       baltimore        2000
1       netflix       baltimore        2000
2       hulu          orlando          2000a
4       hulu          houston            4
```

Here my code below, it works, however I am only getting RPN for every record, not the NPI associated that RPN in mylist

```
#Seperates Portico from Facets, FEP, Nasco, ETC
portico = df[df['SOURCE'] == 'PORTICO']
comparelist = []

#creates a list of RPN and NPI
mylist = portico[['RPN','NPI']].values.tolist()       
for index,x in df.iterrows():
        RPN = x['RPN']
        for a in mylist:
            if RPN in a:
                comparelist.append(a)
            else:
                comparelist.append(RPN)
            break
    df = df.drop(columns = ['NPI'])
    df['NPI'] = comparelist
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
RPN      Source          city           npi
1       netflix       baltimore        1
1       netflix       baltimore        1
2       hulu          orlando          2
4       hulu          houston          4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind creating one more dataframe for `mylist`, one way may be to use `merge`:

```
mylist_df = pd.DataFrame(mylist, columns=['RPN', 'npi']) # creating other df 
df = df.merge(mylist_df, how='left', on='RPN')
df['npi'].fillna(df['RPN'], inplace=True) # fill na values with RPN of same dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you response! unfortunately this didnt work. the problem was that it didnt fill all associated records the NPI number, just its first instance

Comment: Looking at your comments, I think you meant to upvote @ALollz answer.

Answer (score 0):

`map` with a dict + `fillna` to replace unmapped values. Depending upon the shape of `mylist` choose the correct dictionary:

```
d = dict(zip(*mylist)) # if [[1, 2, 3], ['2000', '2000a', '2000b']]
d = dict(mylist)       # if [[1, '2000'], [2, '2000a'], [3,'2000b']]

df['npi'] = df.RPN.map(d).fillna(df.RPN)

#   RPN   Source       city    npi
#0    1  netflix  baltimore   2000
#1    1  netflix  baltimore   2000
#2    2     hulu    orlando  2000a
#3    4     hulu    houston      4
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! this worked gave you an upvote!! @ALollz

Answer (score 0):

This can be viewed as a left join with a `fillna` operation afterwards.

```
my_series = pd.series(index=[1, 2, 3], data=['2000', '2000a', '2000b'], name='RPN')

df = pd.DataFrame({"RPN": [1, 1, 2, 4], "Source": ['netflix', 'netflix', 'hulu', 'hulu']}).set_index("RPN")

result = df.join(my_series, how="left").reset_index()

result = result.fillna(result.RPN, axis=0)
```